# Tor and Windows 10, a combination that can only fail?

Tags: windows

i have been using tor on my older windows version without anything else. how does this look with windows 10? i don't trust windows 10 too much since beeing forced to have it.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you want to know if Tor Browser works in Windows 10 or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm using Tor with windows 10 - it works! Here are some tips for you:

1. First of all, **use the expert bundle**. You need to make a *separate* user, isolated from anything else and having no permissions except `c:\Tor` folder - or another *spaceless latin letters only folder in a root of the drive*. Folder path *is* important - it will save your day many times preventing glitches. Run it as a system service from the isolated user you've created
2. You can make things better using a RAM drive - there's a free one named Radeon RAMDisk, a collaboration of AMD and DataRam, works flawlessly! http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk <-- here is the official website, HTTPS also available, but the msi distribution is signed, so it's not mandatory :) Use the ram disk for your Tor data folder - it will speed some things up just like tmpfs does it on Linux
3. You use it as a proxy **only** if you're just in need to load a website or reach a torrent tracker, i.e. for not so sensitive data. Otherwise you use **VirtualBox** for a full VM isolation *and* VirtualBox's feature to proxify the VM-specific activity [ File -> Preferences -> Proxy ] **and** You're creating an interface for a Host-only(isolated) network for your VM's and put Tor's HTTPS and SOCKS proxy ports there as well.

Basically - that's it! Feel free to ask more specific details if you need ones

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that Tor is primarily a anonymity tool and only secondarily a security tool. Will you be anonymous to websites you visit while using Tor on Windows 10? Yes as long as you know how not to de-anonymize yourself but that's true regardless of your operating system.